# Automatically specifing a default post-build event in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to automatically specify a post build event command? Right now I have to keep putting in the same command for every new project I create. Is there a way to have all new projects default to a specific post build event command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a new project template which includes the post build command.  The template can be derived by creating a new project, adding the post build command and then using that project as the basis for the template.

Creating the template is a bit too involved to capture in a SO answer but here are a few articles on the subject

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx